# Second button click generates exception

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following `HTML`

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child">
        <input type="text" class="text"/>
        <input id="submit" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

and `JS` code

```
function doThis(){
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit);
    myKeys=[];
    myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(submit));
    span.innerHTML=myKeys;
}
function getAllKeyValuePair(obj){
    var str="";
    for(var key in obj){
        try{
            str=str+"{"+key+", "+obj[key]+"}";
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(key);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/8/)**. Second click on the `submit` button generating the following error `Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.` Why this error is occuring? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inserting with `innerHTML` the data created by the function `getAllKeyValuePair()`, you are also duplicating the following code

```
...}{outerHTML,
<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()" value="submit">
}{...
```

That is readed by javascript as another element with the id "submit" duplicating the identifier, causing the error when you try to execute again

```
 var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line `span.innerHTML=myKeys;` is causing the issue because it causes a duplication of the submit button element on the page. Simply change `span.innerHTML=myKeys;` to `span.textContent = myKeys;` and it should work fine.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/8/)**